# Typescript how to type guard promise type not empty if error is empty

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
const [err, value] = await aerr(promise())
if(!err) {
  // value should not be "possibly undefined" here
}
```

I've experimented a lot with crazy data types on the aerr function, but i can't get it to understand that err and value are mutually exclusive. Any ideas?

If you're curious, this is my current mess (it doesn't work)

```
interface AErrResolve<T> {
  [0]:undefined
  [1]:T
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<any>;
}
interface AErrReject<T> {
  [0]:any
  [1]:undefined
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<any>;
}
export function aerr<T>(promise:Promise<T>) {
  return promise.then((x:T):AErrResolve<T> => [undefined, x]).catch((err:any):AErrReject<T> => [err, undefined])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think TypeScript will help you do this the way you want.  It looks like you want the compiler to do [control flow type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to understand that exactly one of the elements of `[err, value]` will be defined.

There are a few reasons why this doesn't work.  You want `[undefined, T] | [any, undefined]` to act as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) where the property value located at key `0` is used as the discriminant property.  This is a problem because TypeScript currently [only supports discriminating values which are finite types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12600), and `any` is infinite.  This is also a problem because in order to check key `0` you have to use bracket notation instead of dot notation, but TypeScript currently [will not apply discriminated union narrowing when you use bracket notation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  Finally, even if you could get this to work, you are destructuring the tuple before checking the discriminant property, and expecting the type narrowing to still happen, but that's apparently [too much for TypeScript to handle](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10976).

If I fix all three of those issues I get something that works but is quite different from what you're looking for:

```
interface AErrResolve<T> {
    type: 'resolved'
    value: T
}
interface AErrReject {
   type: 'rejected'
   err: any
}

declare function aerr<T>(promise: Promise<T>): AErrResolve<T> | AErrReject

async function foo<T>(promise: () => Promise<T>) {
    const result = await aerr(promise())
    if (result.type === 'resolved') {
        result.value // okay
    } else {
        result.err // okay
    }
}
```

This works, which is good, but I don't know if it fits your use case. It's up to you.  Anyway, hope this helps you.  Good luck.

Comment: ty for all the details! it's helpful to know that it's not currently possible, so i should stop wasting time trying to get it working that way ^^; currently i'm doing `if(!value)` instead of `if(err)`, which isn't ideal, but at least it doesn't complain about `err` being possibly undefined there, since it's an any type